# How to save a bool favorite from list of object to Shared Preferences in Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, boolean, sharedpreferences, favorites

I have a list of items i want if i clicked on any of them his bool favorite equal true using shared pref..
in more details I Have a list of objects with a bool favorite attribute. I Want to store this boolean value to shared pref..

Model Class:

```
class ZekrModel {
  final String zekrTitle;
  final String zekrImage;
  final String zekrCat;
  final Widget screenWidget;
  bool isFav;

  bool toggleDone() {
   isFav = !isFav;
  }
}
```

Provider Class:

```
class ZekrProvider with ChangeNotifier{

  List<ZekrModel> _zekrList = [
    ZekrModel(
        zekrTitle: 'أذكار المساء',
        zekrImage: 'assets/images/sunset.png',
        zekrCat: 'Azkar',
        screenWidget: AlmasaaScreen(),
    ),
    ZekrModel(
      zekrTitle: 'أذكار الصباح',
      zekrImage: 'assets/images/sunrise.png',
      zekrCat: 'Azkar',
      screenWidget: AlsabahScreen(),
    )
];

  void updateFav(ZekrModel zekrModel) {
    zekrModel.toggleDone();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  List<ZekrModel> get favZekr {
    return _zekrList.where((element) => element.isFav).toList();
  }
}
```

Usage in UI:

```
 onTap: (){
     value.updateFav(zekrIndex);
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the package:

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
```

Your widget:

```
class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

Then, just call like that inside any method to set a bool:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
prefs.setBool('logado', true);
prefs.setString('logado_email', people.email);
```

If you want to retrieve it later:

```
bool status = prefs.getBool('logado') ?? false;
```

Comment: I know the syntacs but i don't where i should put this bloc of specific! in class model or in provider class or in ui?! Can you show me in my code plz!?

Comment: And don't forgot this element is inside a list of objects

Comment: You should put outside of this method, in the widget scope. You declare the variable in the beginning of the widget, then you could create an async method only to a set the variable bool, because the memory access is async